# ¿Como puedo devolver los valores de -1, 0 y 1 dependiendo del calculo IMC?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
public int calcular_IMC()
{

IMC = this.Peso/(this.Altura*this.Altura);
if (IMC<18.5) 
{
return -1;   //bajo peso 
}
else if (IMC>=18.5 && IMC<=24.9) 
{
return 0; //peso ideal
}
else if (IMC>=25 && IMC<=29.9) 
{
return 1; //sobre peso
}
return ¿?;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O puedes guardar en una variable

```
public int calcular_IMC() { 
  int a=0;// sólo inicial
  IMC = this.Peso/(this.Altura*this.Altura); 
  if (IMC<18.5) { 
      a=-1;//bajo peso
  }
  if (IMC>=18.5 && IMC<=24.9) { 
      a=0; //peso ideal 
  }
  if (IMC>=25 && IMC<=29.9) { 
      a=1; //sobre peso 
  } 
  return a; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es tratar el valor después, te muestro un ejemplo muy simple.

```
public class IMC {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int valor = calcular_IMC();
   //la variable valor guarda el return

    if (valor == 1) {
        System.out.println("cuida tu salud...");

    }

}
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

public static int calcular_IMC() {

    double peso = 65;
    double altura = 1.65;
    double IMC;

    IMC = peso / (altura * altura);
    if (IMC < 18.5) {
        System.out.println("bajo peso");
        return -1;
    } else if (IMC >= 18.5 && IMC <= 24.9) {
        System.out.println("peso ideal");
        return 0; //
    } else if (IMC >= 25 && IMC <= 29.9) {
        System.out.println("sobre peso");
        return 1; //
    } else {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
    return -2;

 }
}
```

Si lo único que quieres es mostrar el valor, lo puedes hacer con una simple `System.out.println("-1");` sin necesidad de un return. Te comparto un ejemplo [Índice masa corporal (IMC)](https://masqueprogramar.wordpress.com/2017/03/14/indice-masa-corporal-imc/)

Comment: Me sirvió de mucho. GRACIAS